# Curl in Kubernetes agent on Jenkins

Tags: docker, kubernetes, jenkins, curl

I have a script that uses curl and that script should be run in Kubernetes agent on Jenkins. Here is my original agent configuration:

```
    pipeline {
        agent {
        kubernetes {
            customWorkspace 'ng-cleaner'
            yaml """
kind: Pod
metadata:
spec:
  imagePullSecrets:
    - name: jenkins-docker
  affinity:
    nodeAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        nodeSelectorTerms:
          - matchExpressions:
              - key: agentpool
                operator: In
                values:
                  - build
  schedulerName: default-scheduler
  tolerations:
    - key: type
      operator: Equal
      value: jenkins
      effect: NoSchedule
  containers:
    - name: jnlp
      env:
        - name: CONTAINER_ENV_VAR
          value: jnlp
    - name: build
      image: tixartifactory-docker.jfrog.io/baseimages/helm:helm3.2.1-helm2.16.2-kubectl.0
      ttyEnabled: true
      command:
        - cat
      tty: true
"""
        }
    }
```

The error message is "curl ....
/home/jenkins/agent/ng-cleaner@tmp/durable-0d154ecf/script.sh: 2: curl: not found"

What I tried:

1. added shell step to main "build" container:
   shell: sh "apk add --no-cache curl", also tried "apt install curl"- didn't help
2. added new container with curl image:
   - name: curl
   image: curlimages/curl:7.83.1
   ttyEnabled: true
   tty: true
   command:
   - cat - didn't help as well

Any suggestions on how I can make it work?

Comment: UPT: I added new container
    - name: curl
      image: curlimages/curl:7.83.1
      ttyEnabled: true
      tty: true
      command:
        - cat
and added this block to my pipeline
container ('curl'){
}
It seems to work, I don't have errors with curl anymore, but the process in this newly added container cannot start: "process apparently never started in /home/jenkins/agent/ng-cleaner@tmp/durable-3ff1be5d
(running Jenkins temporarily with -Dorg.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.BourneShellScript.LAUNCH_DIAGNOSTICS=true might make the problem clearer)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved it.
It was needed to add shell step to main container:

```
shell: sh "apk add --no-cache curl"
```

and then place my script inside container block:

```
stages {
    stage('MyStage') {
        steps {
            container('build'){
                script {
```